# How to delete contact from Gmail app on Android?

Tags: gmail

Using Android 4.4.4 on a SM-J100H.

On the Gmail web interface on a Desktop I deleted a contact, it was just only an e-mail address.

After it I deleted from my Contact list on my phone. When I list my contacts using "All" it doesn't finds it.

I synced my contacts in the settings. I even restarted my phone.

But the problem: When I type in the Gmail app in the "To:" field.... it still appears!! WHY???

I even tried an app called "Contact Remover" but it didn't even found it.

There is NO "list/delete contact" option in the Gmail app.

I even tried to create a new contact with this e-mail address using my phone (contact on gmail) and then delete it, but didn't helped. Synced it too, before deletion.

I don't know that it's just Google want to collect all the e-mail addresses in the world or only the indian programmers were just again idiots.

Question: How could I delete the contact from my Gmail app?

Answer (score -1):

I found it out....

- create contact/email on the phone in the gmail contact list
- sync contact list in settings
- reboot phone
- delete contact on phone and on gmail website
- sync
- reboot
- done, contact cannot be seen anymore in the gmail app..

..my god..